# Jenkins unable to build iOS application: 'Code Sign error: No code signing identities found'

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I have follow the guideline from the following websites to use Jenkins to build iOS apps.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin
http://savvyapps.com/blog/continuous-integration-ios-jenkins

I have exported my developer profile and imported it to Jekins and call before the Xcode build. From the console log, Jenkins installed the provisioning during the build.

```
$ security import /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/developer-profiles/957b9655-81ce-46a0-8686-1f67f7d17a41/developer/identities/18BAD5E662ED3759CD8D7C85E33390324BBD130E.p12 -k jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild -P ******** -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/productsign jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild
$ security import /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/developer-profiles/957b9655-81ce-46a0-8686-1f67f7d17a41/developer/identities/7A5A56DA487E33DE5D16567DC8868B7CD9A865D6.p12 -k jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild -P ******** -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/productsign jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild
$ security import /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/developer-profiles/957b9655-81ce-46a0-8686-1f67f7d17a41/developer/identities/F19D5511EC904BA5CC9D65F306B8CD4D2B0BB19B.p12 -k jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild -P ******** -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/productsign jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild
$ security show-keychain-info jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild
Keychain "jenkins-testApp-1-DevBuild" lock-on-sleep timeout=300s
Installing  0b3a6836-af47-4afd-9484-9ca4ccec6c6d.mobileprovision
Installing  0ef7bac8-0408-4c38-bf6c-3afb004ee451.mobileprovision
Installing  193e9795-97b1-4d4a-981d-a51714e381a4.mobileprovision
```

However the build is fail because of code sign error. Does anyone how to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“Auth-Dev”) were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by copying the development cert from login to System in Keychain access.

Reference: http://code-dojo.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/fix-ios-code-signing-issue-when-using.html